# I want to extract vwap value from the given webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url="https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=KOTAKBANK&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0"

page=urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
infile=urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
data = infile.decode('ISO-8859-1') # Read the content as string decoded with ISO-8859-1


print (soup.find('span', {'id':'vwap'}).text)
```

I am running this code in jupyter; I want output to be displayed as the value of VWAP on the webpage, but nothing is shown as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract from a different tag which has a string containing a lot of useful info including that price after loading with `json`

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=KOTAKBANK&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text.strip())
print(data['data'][0]['averagePrice'])
```